# What to do instead of <a> in <a>?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a new site, using [this bootstrap tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) for collapsing cards.
I want to click on the whole card-header though, not just its button, so I replaced it with an `<a>` tag and removed the button inside.

**But I also want to have multiple other clickable links in the card header and they are dynamically generated `<a>` tags so I will not change their tag type.**

I tried to change the card header to a button to be able to put `<a>` tags in it, but then I can not click them anymore.

**Hoping for some easy creative solution you html-genius can come up with (best would be no addition css and no js at all please) :)**

Keep in mind: I want the card-header and sub-links to have the clickable-mouse-icon on mouseover.

I inserted some code here:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <div class="card">

      <button href="#" id="headingOne" 
              class="card-header mb-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" 
              data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target="#collapseOne" 
              aria-expanded="true" 
              aria-controls="collapseOne">
          
            Some Text
            <a id="alwaysATag" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
            <a id="alwaysATag2" href="#">Clickable Link2</a>
            <a id="alwaysATag3" href="#">Clickable Link3...</a>
          
      </button>


    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<a id="alwaysATag" href="#" width="100%">Clickable Link</a>`  is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I understand your idea, but will this work with multiple <a> tags?

Comment: @badola i think he wants <A id="alwaysATag" href="#" width="100%">Clickable Link 1 with <a id="sublink1">Link 1.1</a> and another <a id="sublink2">LInk 1.2</a> and then some more clickable header</A>

Comment: I made it clearer by adding some more example links

Comment: I'm still not getting what is it that you actually want...

Comment: @WebDevBooster Just what the script shows, but the mouse icon being a click hand and the Clickable Links to work...so pressing those should not affect the collapse

Comment: What you are trying to do is just bad UX. Have a dedicated button to expand and collapse the content. Why have a random click trigger an action?

Comment: @Pablo it's not random, it should be somewhere on that `#heading1` except for the links inside it.

Comment: you mean your problem is you cant click the links now?

Comment: @mohammedqudah yes, and I want the click-mouse-icon

Comment: I know is not random but it sure looks like lt. You are trying to do something cool but is just bad UX.

Comment: i solved it with html only, but for the mouse icon you need css. i think you think that using html only is better but nop you actually have to use css its actually very easy one line only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `button` with `span` because you can't put links in a button in the first place so your code will be like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <div class="card">

      <span id="headingOne" 
              class="card-header mb-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" 
              data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target="#collapseOne" 
              aria-expanded="true" 
              aria-controls="collapseOne">
          
            Some Text
            <a id="alwaysATag" href="/">Clickable Link</a>
            <a id="alwaysATag2" href="http://google.com">Clickable Link2</a>
            <a id="alwaysATag3" href="#">Clickable Link3...</a>
          
      </span>


    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

to make the mouse pointer use this css

`a{cursor: pointer}`

Comment: To add to this, you can add `data-toggle="collapse"` to any HTML element and it will add the toggle action. I does not have to be a button or a link.

Comment: You mentioned a on liner css for the mouse-icon, can you add it?

Comment: by the way i think you will love this it is better than using cards https://mikeghq.github.io/IBootstrap/#Tabs if you have any question about i am happy to help :)

Comment: @mohammedqudah Oh, sorry - the mouse icon for the a's was already there, I meant the span - but I guess the css will also work for that